# Why won't this explode() print?

Tags: php, explode

I'm trying to make a video downloader and am putting the final touches on it but I can't get this simple `explode()` function to print to test.  Here's the code, it's very simple

```
$url = explode('"', $line);
print_r($url[1]);
```

I'm trying to take this input `file: "http://cdn1.videolb2.videsite.com/18092013/2014182.mp4?nvb=20130917201517&nva=20130919201517&hash=0bd94fc24498f1f1bd7e1",` and extract the url by exploding at the `"` but it won't print. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to print `$url[0]`?

Comment: Try to `print_r($url);` to see what's in there, to make sure it's right.

Comment: @Andrew `$url[0]` will be the empty string, will it not?

Comment: [(yes, it will)](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2808802695f26268fda8c6f9be834e2898a89109)

Comment: I suggest you to use regular expression to extract the url from this string.